# How to save UserData in Android FireBase DB?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to Save UserDate in Android FireBase DB.

I have Email, name, age, province data(String Type).

I want to write UserDate like this.

```
 "users": {
"Bart@gmail.com": {
  "name": "Bart",
  "age": "10",
  "province" : "Springfield"
  },
"Lisa@gmail.com": { ... },
}
```

How should I write code to save userdata like this templates?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a json java library like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
>   their JSON representation. (...) Provide simple toJson() and
>   fromJson() methods to convert Java objects to JSON and vice-versa